# Maven overlays and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, maven

I have 2 Maven web projects A and B. B contains some common parts and A depends on B.

In A's pom.xml I have:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have 2 problems:

1. When making some changes in B, if I run a maven build on A I don't see the changes in the resulting exploded archive.
2. Trying to deploy A from Eclipse does not work - the contents of B are not included in the resulting war/exploded archive.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you changes stuff in B, you have to re-install it into your local maven repo (`mvn install`) for other local projects that have it as dependency to receive the latest modifications.

When building a maven project it's best if you build it using Maven (like with commands such as `mvn package`) and not using some other building tool (such as Eclipse). If you wanna build it a la Maven but from the comfort of your Eclipse GUI, you can istall m2_eclipse plugin from :

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html

which integrates Maven with Eclipse. Then, when you rigth click on your project in Eclipse, under the "Run..." options you'll have the one that allows your to Maven build it, redirecting all console output to the Eclipse console window.

And as a final note, in a setup such as the one aboce, ideally you'd create a parent Maven project (packaged as "pom") which has as child projects B and A (in that order). This way if you've modified stuff in both projects and you want everything to be build with the latest modifs, you can just do a maven install on the parent pom and Maven will take care of everything.

Comment: Actually, that's the setting that I already have. I do have m2eclipse, but what I'd like to do would be to have Eclipse handle the deployment so I can deploy and run the projects straight from Eclipse. After all, Eclipse is supposed to be an Integrated Development Environment (emphasis on INTEGRATED). So I'd like to have it handling everything - editing, compiling, building, deploying, running the server and debugging. With my current setting I can't do the deployment from Eclipse (which you can do without any problem if you only have one web project).

Comment: Yes you can, I do the exact same thing u want from Eclipse. Here's an actual example: I have a mvn project configured with the Jetty plugin, right, so that if I do a mvn jetty:run in the command line it will start up in jetty, and any modif I make in Eclipse will be hot deployed. Now, I've made a custom maven runner in eclipse that just executes that mvn jetty:run command. This way I can run it from eclipse.

Comment: The m2eclipse plugin was donated from Sonatype to the Eclipse foundation. Newer versions of the plugin are available from http://www.eclipse.org/m2e

Comment: M2E by itself will not solve the issue with WAR overlays.  For that you need the M2E connector called M2E-WTP (https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp/wiki) which can be installed from within Eclipse via `Preferences->Maven->Discovery->Catalog`.  As an alternative you can get M2E-WTP directly from it's update site.

Answer (score 4):

Amplifying @AndreiBodnarescu's point, you may not be seeing the changes you made to project-B when you build project-A because the changes aren't available in the Maven repository.

If project-B is being built on the same machine can you ensure that you used `mvn install` to install to your local repository?  If project-B is being derived from a build on a *different* machine then use `mvn deploy` to *deploy* project-B to a common shared repository.  In this case you may *still* not pick up project-B if you aren't using SNAPSHOTted versioning or you don't increment project-B's version number.

I see that B is of type `war`.  What is the packaging of A?  Is it an EAR?  If so using the `maven-war-plugin` with project-A is not going to be of help.

Comment: Well not to be a pest, but just so that I can avoid any potential confusion, isn't this what I said as well 40 minutes before?

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu Although there are similarities I felt there were some points that could be added.  Hence my response.  I don't see how my making some suggestions causes "confusion".  For good measure I have edited to refer to your answer as well.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification. I wasn't being sarcastic you know, I was genuinely wondering if I'm missing something or our answers are somewhat similar. At any rate, yours is more to the point, so +1.

Comment: Both projects are of type war, both built on the same machine. I use install to build the projects, but it's true that I did NOT increase the version number. For the moment it's the start of the project and I'm doing lots of small changes and tests and so on, so I figured it doesn't justify a version number increase.