# How to have a proper "overlay" war deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, war

We have a Maven project which use the overlay of war plugin in order to merge 2 wars.

With Eclipse, we have a Tomcat 8 installation (use tomcat installation property checked) in server view.

If we republish the project, only parent compiled files are deployed to Tomcat.

When we take a look in target directory, we have :

- classes directory (of parent),
- war directory (with compiled sources of the second war),
- xxx directory of our project with ALL compiled files merged,
- a xxx war file which is fine too.

It seems Eclipse just deploy "classes" directory into webapps directory of Tomcat.

How to solve it ?

Thank you

Eclipse Neon RC3, Tomcat 8, Maven 3.3.9.
Same problem with Mars...

Comment: So this is an `Eclipse` problem after all ?
Maybe you'll find your solution here with the [m2e plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491308/how-to-handle-maven-war-overlays-in-eclipse)

Comment: yes its an Eclipse problem which is not working as Maven do...all m2E plugins are installed, in last version (20160831).

Comment: Its really a pb. We cant develop & hot deploy changes.

Comment: i have updated all m2e plugin and still have the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to solve this problem.

Eclipse with his plugin doesn't build the project in Maven native way.
We tried on Mars, Neon, Oxygen version with all update which were possible for m2e plugin.