# Is it possible to share Spring Web endpoints between two WAR?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, war

I have two Java + Spring Web 4 (not Spring Boot) web project, the dependencies are managed with Maven and are packaged as WAR.
Since both are almost identical, I'd like to create a common WAR with all the common code and put in these two WARs only the differences.

Here a graphic representation:
[image]

Most of the differences are in the @Controller classes, for example, I have some endpoints with a custom annotation in one project and without on the other. Another difference is that there are some differences in the code inside the @Controller classes.

I have seen that often, the [Maven Overlay is suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491308/how-to-handle-maven-war-overlays-in-eclipse) in a situation like this but it doesn't seem a good solution in this case and is not good during the developments because I'd like to debug each project separately.

Do you have any suggestions?